# How to decipher 4 short vars from a long var using bit manipulations in C++?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, long-integer, short

```
long wxyz; //(w = bits 0-8, x = bits 9-17 , y = bits 18-23, z =  bits 24-29)


short w;

short x;

short y;

short z;

w= wxyz & 0xFF800000;
x= wxyz & 0x007FC000;
y= wxyz & 0x00003F00;
z= wxyz & 0x000000FC;
```

Is this code correct?

Thanks

Comment: A calculator that can display in "binary" is your friend ... that and a pen and paper :P However, remember that's just a mask. You'll want to "shift" the masked bits into the correct space. I prefer to *shift* and *then mask*, because the masks are easier. Also, you don't have to worry about sign-extension at all.

Comment: Usually, bit 0 means the least significant bit. Your formulas use bit 0 as a most significant bit. If that is what intended, then your formulas seem ok. Otherwise, your bit masks are not correct. Yeah, you have to shift the extracted bits.

Comment: please format your code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to shift the bits down.

```
w= (wxyz & 0xFF800000) >> 23;
x= (wxyz & 0x007FC000) >> 14;
y= (wxyz & 0x00003F00) >> 8;
z= (wxyz & 0x000000FC) >> 2;
```

Comment: Your shift amounts are not correct. Should be 23 for the first, 14 for the second, 8 for third, and 2 for fourth.

Comment: @mbaitoff: You're right. I misread the question and just assumed he wanted to split the bits evenly(8 each)

Comment: He said w was bits 0-8, you have it as bits 23-31.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: That depends how you label the bits.  I generally label them in the same order I would read them on paper, most significant digit first, and the OP has yet to specify, but based on his masks, we can guess he labels them the same.

Comment: @PigBen: The least significant bit is always bit 0

Comment: @ ThomasMcLeod: What do you mean "always"?

Comment: Thanks anyway, since you fixed one of my problems.

Comment: @PigBen: let's put it this way: when is it not?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod:  The LSB is the LSB.  Whether you label it 0, 31 or 32 is COMPLETELY arbitrary.  Like I said, based on the OP's masks, he clearly labels it as 31.  I'm answering based on that.  Correct his question, I am anwering his intended question.

Comment: @PigBen: His question could go either way. But it's convention that the LSB is bit 0. It's not an arbitrary convention. The reason LSB is bit 0 is that, if you extend a short to a long, or visa versa, the bit labels do not change.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Funny, I must have missed that convention, and so must and so must have the writers of several manuals for big endian machines. In my experience LSB is mostly called bit 0 on little endian machines like x86, but that doesn't make it general convention except for machine specific topics.

Comment: @Grizzly: Ok, granted, manual writers can label bits any way they desire. But in the absence of some specific context, LSB is bit 0. Independent of any particular machine architecture, this makes sense mathematically, since then the bit label matches the exponent of the place value. I.e., bit 0 is the 1's (2^0) place, bit 1 is the 2's (2^1) place, bit 2 is the 4's (2^2) place, etc.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: so who defines this context independent notation? It seems to make more sense to number bits in memory increasing order (which curiously is whats commonly done, making LSB 0 for little endian and MSB 0 for big endian machines). Considering your mathematical argument: It makes just as much sense to label the MSB  0 and go in ascending order from there. Afterall for any given number (independent whether base 2 or base 10) you would call the digit with the highest exponent (so in this case the MSB) the first digit, and not the one with the lowest. So its all a matter of opinon

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following to get the highest byte from the 4 bytes int `w = (wxyz & 0xFF000000) >> 24`. First apply bit mask and then shift bits to the lowest byte.

Or you can do it other way around - shift, apply bitmask:

```
w = (wxyz >> 24) & 0xFF
x = (wxyz >> 16) & 0xFF
y = (wxyz >> 8) & 0xFF
z = wxyz & 0xFF
```

But isn't it easier to use unions?

Comment: No. Unions cannot be used for bit manipulation, as the standard does not say anything about how elements of a union are to be packed. Any union-based solution will be compiler and CPU specific.

Comment: to get a var of type short do I & with 0xFF or 0xFFFF ?

Comment: The bit slices he has defined are not all 8 bits.

Comment: The problem with unions is not whether the standard states how the elements are laid out, but that all of the elements of the union *share* the same memory space: `union U { int x, y; };` The union has two fields, but both share the same memory, the size of the union will be `sizeof(int)` in this case. You cannot control the memory layout, and it is not a solution. You might have been thinking about *bitfields*, which pack let you interpret different bits as different variables, but that is in fact unspecified by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

```
w =  wxyz & 0x000001ff;
x = (wxyz & 0x0003fe00) >> 9;
y = (wxyz & 0x00fc0000) >> 17;
z = (wxyz & 0x3f000000) >> 23;
```

Edit: need to cast long to short to avoid compiler warning:

```
w = (short) wxyz & 0x000001ff;
x = (short) ((wxyz & 0x0003fe00) >> 9);
y = (short) ((wxyz & 0x00fc0000) >> 17);
z = (short) ((wxyz & 0x3f000000) >> 23);
```

Comment: Umm, OP please ignore this reply.

Comment: Actually I think this answer is correct too considering bit 0 to 8 are the least significant bits.

Comment: It was wrong at the time wrote the comment, and has been edited since, a few times.

Answer (score 0):

Hold on -- what do you mean by bits 0-8? This usually means the nine least significant bits, in which case you've grasped the wrong end of the int.

Comment: I think you are right, bit 0 to 8 are the least significant bits. But I guess thanks to all the responses, I now have at least 2 ways to handle it , however I have to use the correct end of the long.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I prefer to handle this, by "inching". It just makes more sense in my head. Also, unlike a mask and then shift, there is *no problem* of a >> being sign-extending (C/C++ isn't Java or C# in well-definedness there). I am going with the assumption that 0 is the MSB (and there are 32bits total, although a long *can* be more), as stated in the question.

```
long wxyz = ...; //(w = bits 0-8, x = bits 9-17 , y = bits 18-23, z =  bits 24-29)

wxyz >>= 2; // discard 30-31 (or, really, "least two insignificant")

z = wzyz & 0x3f; // easy to see this is "6 bits", no?
wzyz >>= 6; // throw them out

y = wzyz & 0x3f;
wzyz >>= 6;

x = wzyz & 0x1ff;
wzyz >>= 9;

w = wzyz & 0x1ff;
wzyz >>= 9; // for fun, but nothing consumes after
```

P.S. Adjusting for types is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: You're off by an inch:) The last inch should be anded with 0x1ff and shifted by 9 (for fun). This is because 0-8 is 9 in length.

Comment: @Michael Smith Absolutely correct (question is updated to reflect) ;-) I should have also added "testing for validity is left as an exercise to the reader".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different solution you can use.

```
long wxyz;
short w, x, y, z;
char* buf = new char[sizeof(long)];
buf = (char*)long; // cast long as byte array
w = (short)buf[0]; // The way you sort depends on endianness
x = (short)buf[1];
y = (short)buf[2];
z = (short)buf[3];
delete[] buf;
```

Answer (score -1):

Partially correct.  You'll have to shift them to the right if you want the values of each segment.

```
short w = (short)((wxyz & 0xFF800000) >> 23);
short x = (short)((wxyz & 0x007FC000) >> 14);
short y = (short)((wxyz & 0x00003F00) >> 8);
short z = (short)((wxyz & 0x000000FC) >> 2);
```

These are correct values.

Comment: @Michael Smith: `These are correct values.` No they're not. For instance, z will always be equal to 0 mod 4, which was surely not in the original spec.

Comment: @TonyK: Edited the z assignment to shift the rvalue by 2 instead.  Stand corrected.  However I get points for most correct :)

Comment: @Michael Smith: No you don't. Bits 0-8 are the least significant bits, not the most significant. Don't be smug.

Comment: @TonyK: C'mon, have a sense of humour.  This is an open forum for open minds.  Of course 0-8 are the least significant, but just answer the question for how it was asked.

Comment: @Michael Smith: Have a sense of your own limitations. "These are correct values". "However I get points for most correct." This doesn't scream 'OPEN MIND' to me!

Comment: @Michael Smith: But where's the joke? I don't get it.

Comment: The smiley face following "most correct". The "These are correct values" was simply to try to attract the OP because at the time of writing it not one of 6 or so answers were correct (at the time).  My answer was also incorrect and I "Stand corrected", as stated previously, but it was closest.  It's all in good humour. That's all I'm trying to say.